# PYTHON: IF statement with Parameters from a file not working correctly

Tags: python, file

I am creating a program that the user can set the odds of a good roll. The variable is stored in a file so that it can be used even when you close the program. My problem is that only the first state of the `if` statement gets executed and I cannot figure out why.

```
file = open("rolltype.txt", "r")
user = input("Enter what you want to roll[e.x: 2d8]: ")
if file.readline() == "1":
    print("Favor")
    favor(user)
elif file.readline() == "2":
    print("AGAINST")
    against(user)
elif file.readline() == "3" or file.readline() == None:
    print("NEUTRAL")
    check(user)
file.close()
```

I open the file in read mode and in the `if` statement I check 4 possible scenarios, and call the appropriate function.
If the file contains the value `1` then the program executes correctly, and if not, the `elifs` get jumped over.

Side-note: the `print()` inside the `if` are used for debugging.
Thank you for taking the time to read and maybe try to help. Have a great rest of the day!

Comment: `tmp = file.readline()` and then use `if "1" in tmp`, `if "2" in tmp`, etc.

Comment: every time `readline()` is executed the pointer is moved to the next line, hence you only should call `readline()` once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

- `readline()` on a file includes the newline at the end of the line. It will never match "1" or any other string that doesn't end with a newline.
- You're comparing a *different* line each time because of the multiple calls to `readline()`. Every time `readline()` is executed, the pointer is moved to the next line. If the file doesn't contain enough lines, some of them are going to return the empty string, and it won't match anything either.

Solution: call `readline()` once into a variable and use `strip()` to take off the newline (and any other whitespace).

```
num_from_file = readline().strip()
if num_from_file == "1":
```

Answer (score 3):

Every time you call `file.readline()`, it is reading the next line in the file.

Therefore, you will get a different result for every conditional expression.

In order to solve this, you should simply store the value in a variable and check that in your conditional expressions:

```py
user = input("Enter what you want to roll[e.x: 2d8]: ")
value = file.readline()

if value == "1":
    print("Favor")
    favor(user)
elif value == "2":
    print("AGAINST")
    against(user)
elif value == "3" or value == None:
    print("NEUTRAL")
    check(user)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call `file.readline()` it reads a new line from the file. This can be fixed by assigning it to a variable before the if statements.

```
line = file.readline()
if line == "1":
  print("Favor")
elif line == "2":
  print("Against")
elif line == "3":
  print("Nuetral")
```

However, I don't think that readline always trims trailing whitespace. Therefore, I suggest using `file.readline().strip()`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your problem, but I already encounter something similar. It was because the use of readline() multiple times. 
Can't you just use :

```py
fileContent = file.readline()
user = input("Enter what you want to roll[e.x: 2d8]: ")
        if fileContent == "1":
            print("Favor")
            favor(user)
        elif fileContent == "2":
            print("AGAINST")
            against(user)
        elif fileContent == "3" or fileContent == None:
            print("NEUTRAL")
            check(user)
        file.close()
```

I am not sure about my answer because I don't understand how your file is written.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code by using dictionaries to define a value to print mapping `print_dct` , and value to function mapping `func_dct`
Also you can use `with` to open your file, so that you would not need to close it explicitly.

```
user = input("Enter what you want to roll[e.x: 2d8]: ")

print_dct = {"1": "Favor", "2": "AGAINST", "3": "NEUTRAL"}
func_dct = {"1": favor, "2": against, "3": user}


with open("rolltype.txt", "r") as file:
    value = file.readline()

    if value == None:
        print(print_dct['3'])
        check(user)

    elif value in print_dct:
        print(print_dct[value])
        func_dct[value](user)
```